# Working during the summer while studying PhD

Tags: working-visas, student-visa

I'm not currently a PhD student but I'm seeking out ways to gain work experience while studying PhD as a Chinese citizen. I read that F-1 visa is just for study, not work. Are there any ways for international students on F-1 visa to work off-campus?

Answer (score 3):

No, the F1 student visa does not permit off campus employment during the first year studying in the US. After a year, US Citizenship & Immigration Services (USCIS) may give permission to work off-campus, but only in specified types of employment, all of which has to be directly related to the student’s major area of study.

**[Employment](https://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/students-and-exchange-visitors/students-and-employment)**

> F-1 students may not work off-campus during the first academic year, but may accept on-campus employment subject to certain conditions and restrictions. After the first academic year, F-1 students may engage in three types of off-campus employment.
>
> - Curricular Practical Training (CPT)
> - [Optional Practical Training (OPT) (pre-completion or post-completion)](https://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/students-and-exchange-visitors/students-and-employment/optional-practical-training)
> - [Science, Technology, Engineering, and Mathematics (STEM) Optional Practical Training Extension](https://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/students-and-exchange-visitors/students-and-employment/stem-opt) (OPT)